# Classes with attributes but no methods

Tags: python-3.x, class, methods

I am a beginner, but I am trying to implement a board game (Orleans) in python. I have created a class for the game state, and a class for each player. I had thought about creating a class for each type of action space, and creating an instance of the action space for each player since each player has a common set of action spaces. Each of these action space classes have some attributes, normally set in an `__init__()` method. However they have no other methods. Is this a good use of classes, or should I just change the code to work with lots of separate variables instead? The reason I made them classes was so that the naming of the variables would be more intuitive. The code below gives an example of the player class and two of the action space classes:

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self, start_characters, name):
        // other attributes
        self.farmhouse = Farmhouse()
        self.village = Village()

class Farmhouse:

    def __init__(self):
        self.boatman = False
        self.craftsman = False

class Village:

    def __init__(self):
        self.farmer = False
        self.boatman = False
        self.craftsman = False
```

The game state class will then have functions that will take a player instance as an argument, testing whether an action space has each of the appropriate requirements to trigger that action.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's good for readability, and there is no problem in defining classes that essentially group related data together. You may even want to do that to reduce the number of arguments you need to pass to a function, for example. As for having just a method, if this wasn't really about data, I would say define functions instead. Not the case here.

What alternatives do you have? Maybe setup dicts in `__init__` with setting names in the keys. Not much different behind the scenes.

I prefer your option for the resulting access syntax.

Comment: Thanks. I've been watching and reading a lot about OOP stuff and have seen it said that you shouldn't have classes with just one method. For example this.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3Do9pEzgHorH0&ved=2ahUKEwiJ5pe_hPLdAhXMBsAKHRnpApMQwqsBMAB6BAgIEAU&usg=AOvVaw0AQidakOj1Gv-egzdRn5R6

Comment: I saw the link, thanks.

There are a lot of good principles and heuristics we should know and follow. But as they are generic, always use common sense for your concrete case. In the end it even clearly agrees with my answer. He says some controversial or even fun things, reflected in the video comments. Different examples could be given, defending some opposite opinions. I will sum it to something like: less code is better, simple is better, you won't gonna need it, but readability matters. Still, don't overengineer it. But the abstractions will live...

Comment: @TaxpayersMoney, notice that it is a lot more important to clearly understand the code by reading it, than it is for the code to be small. If you write a lot of small unreadable code you end up with a large unreadable application no one wants to maintain, not even yourself.

Answer (score 12):

Doing this is called an "Anemic object" or ["Anemic domain"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model) model.

Some consider this an anti-pattern and some not. I generally favor an anemic model as it proves to be a little more readable and scalable in my taste.

Instead of creating classes like that though, I highly suggest you to use [**dataclasses**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) for this type of behavior.

Another option, for immutable types is to use [**namedtuples**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).