# Use class attributes, property or dataclass?

Tags: python, class, properties, attributes, python-dataclasses

I am working on connecting to an API and fetching information about employees.
When creating the employee class, I got confused between:

- using a class ***with attributes only and no methods*** which is [considered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52679693/classes-with-attributes-but-no-methods) anti-pattern.
- using class with property decorators, which I am not sure if it is the best practice in my case.
- using a dataclass, but include some processing (API authentication and creating some attributes) in the `__post_init__()` method.

Here are the 3 alternatives:
**1- Using a class with attributes only ([Anemic domain model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model)):**

```
import api_library


class Employee:
    def __init__(self, system_user: str, system_password: str, employee_mail: str):
        self.context = api_library.authentication(usename=system_user, passwoed=system_password)
        self.user = self.context.users.get_user_by_email(email=employee_mail)

        self.full_name = self.user.display_name
        self.team = self.user.primary_team
        self.manager = self.user.manager.display_name
        self.department = self.user.department.display_name
```

**2- Using `@property` decorator:**

```
import api_library

from typing import Optional


class Employee:
    def __init__(self, system_user: str, system_password: str, employee_mail: str):
        self.context = api_library.authentication(username=system_user, password=system_password)
        self.user = self.context.users.get_user_by_email(email=employee_mail)

    @property
    def full_name(self) -> Optional[str]:
        return self.user.display_name

    @property
    def team(self) -> Optional[str]:
        return self.user.primary_team

    @property
    def manager(self) -> Optional[str]:
        return self.user.manager.display_name

    @property
    def department(self) -> Optional[str]:
        return self.user.department.display_name
```

**3- Using dataclass (but with some processing in `__post_init__()`):**

```
import api_library

from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from config import system_user, system_password


@dataclass
class Employee:
    email: str
    full_name: str = field(init=False)
    team: str = field(init=False)
    manager: str = field(init=False)
    department: str = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        context = api_library.authentication(username=system_user, password=system_password)
        user = context.users.get_user_by_email(email=self.email)
        self.full_name = user.display_name
        self.team = user.primary_team
        self.manager = user.manager.display_name
        self.department = user.department.display_name
```

- Which option is more pythonic?
- Is there a better way to solve this?

I am using `Python 3.10` or `Python 3.8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handle authentication and retrieval separately from instantiating the class (or more precisely, initializing the object after it has been instantiated).

```
import api_library


class Employee:

    def __init__(self, full_name, team, manager, department):
        self.full_name = full_name
        self.team = team
        self.manager = manager
        self.department = department

    @classmethod
    def from_api(cls, system_user: str, system_password: str, employee_mail: str):
        context = api_library.authentication(usename=system_user, password=system_password)
        user = context.users.get_user_by_email(email=employee_mail)

        return cls(user.display_name, user.primary_team, user.manager.display_name, user.department.display_name)


e = Employee.from_api("bob", "12345", "bob@example.com")
```

Like most good `__init__` methods, this is now boilerplate that you *can* implement using a dataclass if you like.

```
@dataclass
class Employee:
    full_name: str
    team: str
    manager: str
    department: str


    @classmethod
    def from_api(cls, system_user: str, system_password: str, employee_mail: str):
        context = api_library.authentication(usename=system_user, password=system_password)
        user = context.users.get_user_by_email(email=employee_mail)

        return cls(user.display_name, user.primary_team, user.manager.display_name, user.department.display_name)
```

Whether you further break `from_api` down into, for example, a method that takes a context or the return value of `get_user_by_email` as an argument is a topic for discussion that is, I think, beyond the scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think the pythonic way (separation of concerns) to achieve this is that you have to separate the Employee class from the api_library

In my opinion the execution sequence should be:
1 authenticate the user
2 retrieve user properties by email
2 create an employee object (Employee class gets user properties as parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Data classes are sometimes considered a *code smell*. The *Data Class Builders* chapter of Fluent Python (2nd ed.) starts with this quote:

> "Data classes are like children. They are okay as a starting point,
> but to participate as a grownup object, they need to take some
> responsibility." (Martin Fowler and Kent Beck, Refactoring, first
> edition, Chapter 3, “Bad Smells in Code, Data Class” section, page 87)

This makes sense if we take the OOP best practice of all classes containing both state and behaviour as gospel. However, Python is a multi-paradigm language and sometimes function-based code passing (ideally immutable) data around is a lot simple and easier to read/maintain. Some go as far as to suggest [avoiding writing classes in Python at all](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0).

My suggestion would be to remove the logic from the data class altogether. This is a very rough idea of what I suggest.

```py
# data.py
import dataclasses


@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
class Employee:
    email: str
    full_name: str
    team: st
    manager: str
    department: str
```

```py
# services.py


def get_employee(user_store: UserDataStoreAdaptor, email: str) -> Employee:
    user = user_store.get_user_by_email(email=self.email)
    return Employee(email=user.email,
                    full_name=user.display_name,
                    team=user.primary_team,
                    manager=user.manager.display_name,
                    department=user.department.display_name)
```

This code would be used in a request handler function of an HTTP API, an event listener, or some business logic function etc. like so:

```
import api_library
import services
from config import system_user, system_password


def do_some_high_level_business_logic(email: str, **kwargs):
    user_api_client = api_library.authentication(username=system_user,
                                                 password=system_password)
    employee = services.get_employee(user_api_client, email)
    ...
```

Comment: "Dataclasses are considered a code smell by proponents of object-oriented programming". Citation needed. There's nothing special about a dataclass; it's not even a special kind *of* class. `dataclass` is just a code generator that allows you to declaratively specify (via type hints, primarily) how to define certain magic methods for the class.

Comment: Thanks @chepner I've changed the phrase to "data classes" to better fit the more general context of the alleged "code smell". I also added a citation (which luckily I could pull from Fluent Python)

Comment: It's not clear what their definition of "data class" is. Are they just objecting to a class with no methods? Would they object to something like a `namedtuple`? Ignoring methods, a class is just a product type with fancy syntax.

Comment: "Are they just objecting to a class with no methods?" I think so, though they distinguish data classes from "records", where "records" are immutable. I can't find the first edition of the book, but here's the Data Classes code smell section from the current edition of the book. https://pastebin.com/JEyGARTV

Comment: The language is toned down a lot in the current edition, which makes me think the first edition was written in the heyday of OOP.

Comment: Ah, I can see the objection if they are distinguishing between mutable and immutable product types (records, structs, classes: it's just variations on a theme :) ).